# How to create a turtle loop in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

how do I create a turtle control structure in Python? In this program, if I type N it works, but if I type Y it results in an error? can someone rewrite this code and provide feedback? Thanks.

```
turtle.shape("turtle")
s = turtle.getscreen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
def triangle():
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/3)


def square():
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/4)

def circle():
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.circle(90)
        

answer = input(" Please type any shape you desire. Options: Triangle, Square, and Circle(MUST BE LOWERCASE)")
if answer ==('triangle'):
    triangle()

elif answer == ('square'):
    square()

elif answer == ('circle'):
    circle()

else:
    print ('Input is wrong')
```

Comment: What are you inputting and what do you expect should occur?

Comment: The program will ask you what shape you would like to input, then turtle draws the shape. Then it will ask you if you want to continue the program, if I say yes it will restart, but the thing is if I say no it will prompt me with "Okay, have a good day" then restart the program again. I tried to use break but it doesn't work because it says it's outside a loop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is roughly a working version of your program.  It doesn't explicitly ask if you want to continue, but simply prompts for a new shape and exits if you give it anything else.  You should be able to rework it to fit your desired `"Okay, have a good day"` interface:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def triangle():
    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/3)

def square():
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/4)

def circle():
    turtle.circle(-50/2)  # radius of 25, drawn clockwise

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')

while True:
    answer = screen.textinput("Shape you desire", "triangle, square, or circle (Must be lowercase)?")

    turtle.clear()

    if answer == 'triangle':
        triangle()
    elif answer == 'square':
        square()
    elif answer == 'circle':
        circle()
    else:
        break

screen.bye()
```

Comment: Uh hello, this is helpful, but can you add the code where it tells you if you want to continue or not? I'm new to python and I want to know what I'm diving into